# Powershell script to launch SSH session

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, scripting

I was looking to see if there is a script, bat or ps1(preferred), that can be made to launch an ssh session to a remote server.
I have been using this method for a little and wanted to speed things up when needing to jump into a session.

Looking to change directory to the folder with server files - \server\folder
Then exec: 
`ssh -i key.pem name@1.2.3.4 password`

Other suggestions are welcome but really prefer powershell as terminal

Comment: Look at the POSH-SSH module then just write a function to create a session when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PuTTY as well, I've been using it recently to build a pre-deploy script for a .NET Core application, I've managed to get a proper SSH connection I just can't copy the contents of my build to server:

[Copying contents of .NET build folder to Ubuntu Server using p-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794049/copying-contents-of-net-build-folder-to-ubuntu-server-using-p-link)

Feel free to use what works on there though!