# Copying contents of .NET build folder to Ubuntu server using Plink

Tags: powershell, ssh, .net-core, file-transfer, plink

I'm building a pre-deploy script in PowerShell that creates a production build of my .NET Core Web Api application and then SSHs into my Ubuntu Digital Ocean Droplet via SSH key.

I'm currently at a stage where I create the build, copy the build folder using `Copy-Item`, SSH into my server and then this is where I'm completely stuck.

I know that I can run BASH commands from my PowerShell script because I've tried some basic operations like creating and deleting a directory, I can `cd` in and out of directories. I've tried storing the copied .NET build folder in memory as a variable: 
`$build = Copy-Item -Path $projectBuildPath -Recurse` and then found out that this can't be done (shame really, that would have been cool) and then opening a session to my server via p-link cli like so:

```
plink.exe -ssh -i $SSHKeyLocation $linuxRemoteHost "cd path\to\server\build-folder && paste ${build}"
```

But again because you can't store copied directories in memory, this failed.

My PowerShell script looks like this:

```bsh
$projectRootDir
$projectBuildPath
$linuxRemoteHost
$SSHKeyLocation

Set-Location $projectRootDir
Write-Host "Building .NET application..."

dotnet publish --configuration Release --verbosity normal

Write-Host "Built Successfully..."
Write-Host "Copying project build files"

$build = Copy-Item -Path $projectBuildPath -Recurse
# fails, for obvious reasons

Write-Host "Remoting into MusicPortal Server..."

plink.exe -ssh -i $SSHKeyLocation $linuxRemoteHost "cd path\to\server\build-folder && paste ${build}"
# SSH Connection successful, paste command fails

Write-Host "Remote successfull, transfering build files..."

exit 0
```

What should I do in order to successfully paste the copied directory to my server? I'm such a noob with PowerShell and SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite strange to try to use `plink` to upload files to a server. As you didn't give any particular reason, why you want to use `plink`, I'm assuming that it's a mistake.

You do not want to use `plink`. You want to use [`psftp`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) or [`pscp`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) (both part of the same PuTTY package as `plink`).

```
pscp -r -i $SSHKeyLocation $projectBuildPath $linuxRemoteHost:/path/to/server/build-folder/
```

Comment: You can assume correctly!!! Haha 

I've honestly just been looking to get more into PowerShell because even though I really love using tooling, I want to understand how it works and remove my dependence on 3rd parties :)  

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I guess I better get my head down into some docs!

Comment: PowerShell/.NET/Windows have no built-in support for SSH/SFTP/SCP. You have to use a 3rd party software or a library or an optional Windows component for it.

Comment: This answer would have been true as of Powershell 5 but powershell core 6 comes with cross platform SSH https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6 I found this not too long after you answered my question :) im still going to use PuTTY though as I've got it working now haha

Comment: That's what I was referring to by *"an optional Windows component"*. It's still not built-in, you have to install it (as well as PowerShell 6).

Comment: Ahhhh okay, see the docs make it sound like it's part of Powershell or a package that's at least part of core... I guess that's what I get for assuming