# How can i transfer image files from local machine to remote server using plink

Tags: putty, plink

Usually we use SCP or PSCP to transfer files between local machine and remote machine. But i need to know if there's a way i can transfer image/text files between machines using PLINK.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why would you want to use Plink? It's doable but it does not make any sense. And it's hardly a programming question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57794049/850848

Answer (score 0):

To post a file from local machine to remote machine, following command works.

```
plink ubuntu@111.111.01.xyz  -pw password  < "D:\\CSV\\001.jpg" "cat > /home/001.jpg"
```

This will transfer `001.jpg` from local machine's `D:\\CSV\\001.jpg` directory  to `home/` directory of remote machine.

Background: I did not have permission to transfer file to remote server using PSCP. I could use plink, and it worked.

Comment: What kind of *"permission"* do you mean?

Comment: Also, there no need to double the backslashes in the path.

Answer (score 0):

This will transfer a.txt from the machine you execute the command to the base folder of the machine your connecting.

```
plink username@10.20.30.40 -pw password < C:\Users\username\Desktop\a.txt "cat > ~/a.txt"
```